# How to close hanged pane in Terminator?

Tags: mc, gnome-terminator

Sometimes I get Terminator panes hanged, probably due to network or remote host failure. How to close such a pane without affecting other panes?

---

If Midnight commander was ran, then right click menu doesn't work. If terminal was hanged while MC was running, right-click also doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work for you to right-click on the pane and select 'Close'?

Comment: @sudodus no, it doesn't; nothing appears on right click on hanged terminal, only on alive one and depending on application running

Comment: Have you tried to double-rightclick on that pane? It works for me with `mc` and `htop`. Otherwise, maybe you can identify the process number of the program, that no longer works, for example `sftp` with a command like `ps -Af | grep sftp` and `kill` that process.

Comment: Try Shift + right-click. Some applications, such as Midnight Commander, are interested in mouse events. In that case a simple right-click is forwarded to that application, whereas Shift + right-click is still handled by Terminator itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> ? It should close the pane that the focus is currently on.